# SQL: given an array of strings, filter if a string column is partially contained in this array

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table Schema

```
Tags
----
["foo"]
["foo2", "bar"]
["bar", "foo_bar"]
["bar"]
```

The content of the `Tags` column is a json string.

Assuming the array is `["foo", "foo_bar"]`, any tag contained in this array needs to be filtered out, so the expected output will be

```
Tags
----
["foo2", "bar"]
["bar"]
```

The query statement I currently use is similar to the following

```sql
SELECT tags
FROM table
WHERE (
    -- Translate the array into cases
    CASE
        WHEN tags like '%"foo"%' THEN false  -- filter out "foo"
        WHEN tags like '%"foo_bar"%' THEN false -- filter out "foo_bar"
        ...  -- filter out others in the given array
        ELSE true
    END
)
```

I want to know if there is a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Does SQLite support arrays?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Take a look at my current query, I've split the array into case statements

Comment: Can you explain why `["foo2", "bar"]` is in your expected results and `["foo"]` is not?

Comment: Why isn't ["foo"] in your expected results?

Comment: For the example you give, I would expect the `INSTR` function to be more efficient than the `LIKE` operator. But testing will determine which executes fewer machine instructions. If your example desired to match two double quoted strings with different prefixes or suffixes, then `INSTR` would not functionally work but neither would the `LIKE` operator work either. For that, you'd have to use regular expressions.

Comment: @forpas Because the array contains foo. if any tag in the tags is in the given array, this row needs to be filtered.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the array as a json string, you can use [JSON1 extension functions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) and aggregation with the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
WITH cte(tag) AS (SELECT json_each.value FROM json_each('["foo", "foo_bar"]'))
SELECT t.tags
FROM tablename t, json_each(tags)
GROUP BY t.tags
HAVING SUM(json_each.value IN cte) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f01decef4ca7b3974fbbfa41711a8163).

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a simple test and find json parsing is significantly slower than string comparison directly. About 20 times slower 

Comment: @BB9z you need json parsing because you store data as json. If you had a normalized table then the solution would be simpler and the performance better.